# Do the UN Security Council's policies include any way to pass a resolution when one member vetos?

Tags: international-relations, international-law, united-nations

The [U.N. Security Council](http://www.un.org/en/sc/) can pass resolutions which all U.N. member states are required to comply with. 5 of these are permanent members. The permanent members can veto any action of the Security Council.

In 1950 the Security Council passed SC Resolution 83, which sanctioned the use of combined forces to repel the North Korean invasion of South Korea. The action passed - partially because the Soviet Union was boycotting the United Nations at the time.

I am wondering what could have happened if the Soviet Union had vetoed this resolution. Did the UN's policies in 1950* contain a way to pass a resolution if one of the permanent members vetoes it? Could the UN have intervened another way if the Soviet Union had vetoed this resolution?

---

*Shortly after this the U.N. passed [Resolution 377](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_377), which allows the General Assembly to act when the 5 permanent members of the Security Council don't agree. This question is about what tools were available prior to Resolution 377*

Comment: I didn't see this Q when it was first posted, but I would now point out that the title question says "Do..." which is present tense, yet the body is asking about the rules from 70 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

No, the veto procedures of the UNSC has stayed the same since prior to 1950.

The 5 constituent veto holders has changed twice, when The ROC was replaced by the PRC and when the USSR was replaced by Russia.